# Unable to get location using Geolocation/HTML5/Phonegap since 2 days ago

Tags: cordova, geolocation, location

My code was working just fine, used to get a location and search nearest subjects (cars), but suddenly it stopped working and always fails on trying to get the location, returning a "Time out expired".

Tried in several devices and always the same:

```js
 var getLocation = function() { 
    document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = '<img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" />';
    document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = '<img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" />';

    var suc = function(p) {
        document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = p.coords.latitude;
        document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = p.coords.longitude;
    };
    var locFail = function(error) {
        document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = 'not found';
        document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = 'not found';
    };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(suc, locFail, {maximumAge: 0,timeout: 6000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(suc, locFail, {maximumAge:3000,timeout: 6000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
```

put maximumAge:3000 ,in your code it is 0 that's why you are getting error.